# SQL Server... Union all on two IF conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two table valued function wich i need to do some selects...
I was trying to do UNION on that selects but i can't do "union all" to my IF...
It should return one row and two columns each if condition...
This code should return :

```
September | 50

October   | 33
```

how can i do this ?!

this was my code :

```
IF (select TotalTreinos from dbo.tbl_CALCULA_TREINOS_MES('20160901','20160930',2,5)) = (SELECT Presencas FROM DBO.tbl_CALCULA_PRESENCAS('Setembro',9,2)) 
    SELECT 'Setembro' as Mes, 100 AS PercentPresencas
else
    select 'Setembro' as Mes, (((SELECT Presencas FROM DBO.tbl_CALCULA_PRESENCAS('Setembro',9,2)) * 100) / (select TotalTreinos from dbo.tbl_CALCULA_TREINOS_MES('20160901','20160930',2,5))) as PercentPresencas

union all

IF (select TotalTreinos from dbo.tbl_CALCULA_TREINOS_MES('20161001','20161031',2,5)) = (SELECT Presencas FROM DBO.tbl_CALCULA_PRESENCAS('Outubro',10,2)) 
    SELECT 'Outubro' as Mes, 100 AS PercentPresencas
else
    select 'Outubro' as Mes,(((SELECT Presencas FROM DBO.tbl_CALCULA_PRESENCAS('Outubro',10,2)) * 100) / (select TotalTreinos from dbo.tbl_CALCULA_TREINOS_MES('20161001','20161031',2,5))) as PercentPresencas
```

Comment: Can you include some sample table data?

Comment: If values are equal then division will return 1, no? What are those IFs there for?

Answer (score 1):

The `IF` statement in T-SQL is an imperative statement, not part of the SQL language. What you want to do is move that `IF` statement inside of the query, where you should use `CASE` instead:

```
SELECT 
  'Setembro' AS Mes, 
  CASE WHEN (SELECT TotalTreinos FROM dbo.tbl_CALCULA_TREINOS_MES('20160901','20160930',2,5)) 
          = (SELECT Presencas FROM DBO.tbl_CALCULA_PRESENCAS('Setembro',9,2)) 
       THEN 100
       ELSE (((SELECT Presencas FROM DBO.tbl_CALCULA_PRESENCAS('Setembro',9,2)) * 100) 
            / (SELECT TotalTreinos FROM dbo.tbl_CALCULA_TREINOS_MES('20160901','20160930',2,5)))
  END AS PercentPresencas
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  'Outubro' AS Mes, 
  CASE WHEN (SELECT TotalTreinos FROM dbo.tbl_CALCULA_TREINOS_MES('20161001','20161031',2,5)) 
          = (SELECT Presencas FROM DBO.tbl_CALCULA_PRESENCAS('Outubro',10,2)) 
       THEN 100
       ELSE (((SELECT Presencas FROM DBO.tbl_CALCULA_PRESENCAS('Outubro',10,2)) * 100) 
            / (SELECT TotalTreinos FROM dbo.tbl_CALCULA_TREINOS_MES('20161001','20161031',2,5))) 
  END AS PercentPresencas
```

Further improvement with CTE by factoring out common expressions:

```
WITH 
  t1 (Mes, StartDate, EndDate) AS (
    -- Of course, these could be calculated also automatically, but you get the idea...
    SELECT 'Setembro', '20160901', '20160930'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Outubro', '20161001', '20161031'
  ), 
  t2 (Mes, TotalTreinos, Presencas) AS (
    SELECT
      Mes,
      (SELECT TotalTreinos FROM dbo.tbl_CALCULA_TREINOS_MES(StartDate,EndDate,2,5)),
      (SELECT Presencas FROM DBO.tbl_CALCULA_PRESENCAS(Mes,10,2))
    FROM t1
  )
SELECT 
  Mes, 
  CASE WHEN TotalTreinos = Presencas
       THEN 100
       ELSE Presencas * 100 / TotalTreinos
  END AS PercentPresencas
FROM t2
```

Comment: Obrigado... funcionou perfeito...
Deu para adaptar ao que eu preciso...

Comment: @HelderPinto: Sorry, I don't speak Portuguese :)

Comment: Sorry.. just saying that it worked perfectly... just with small adapts to my needs... Thanks very much...